# Fragment saveInstanceState is coming as null after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with action bar tab. Each tab contain a fragment. Now when I rotate my device, bundle in my corresponding fragment is coming as null. This is taken care when I using device post android 3.2, but it is happening when device is Andoird3.0. I am having a headache after working on this issue. I crossed check various link on SO, but no help. Although I have given enough details, still will provide some code snippet as at various cases user ask for code snippet.

In my fragment class I am storing this value

```
 @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("textboxVisible", true);
    }
```

this is storing one  boolean variable which it retrived as below.

```
/**
 * Function called after activity is created. Use this
 * method to restore the previous state of the fragment
 */
     @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) 
    {
        //restore the state of the text box
        boolean textboxVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("textboxVisible");
        if (textboxVisible) 
        {
            //do some stuff
        }                   
    }
}
```

but after rotation **savedInstanceState** is coming as null.
I don't what is going wrong. I have read in some document that below 3.2 the onCreateView() of 
fragment is not called with bundle value.  But to deal with this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using android:configChanges ??

Comment: Also, Have you tried setRetainInstance(true); ????

Comment: Basically I am using two different layout for landscape and portrait mode. So can't use android:configChange. And setRetainInstance(true), i ahve not used in current scenario but I have used it earlier, it was not working. Still will give a try in current scenario also

Comment: @Faizan setRetainInstance(true) is of no help. Its not working:(

Answer (score 4):

if you use setRetainInstance(true) the savedInstance bundle is always gonna be null after orientation changed. SO you cannot really save something with it, but what you can do if you need to save something, is to put it in a data member of the fragment, because setRetainInstance(true) preserves the fragment and doesn't destroy it, so after the device was rotated you gonna have the same values.

Comment: Awesome, this really helped me! Just used an instance variable of type Bundle and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

Try to get the `savedInstanceState` in `onCreate` of the `Fragment`.
Like

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // IT MUST NOT BE NULL HERE
        }
    }
```

Please try... i hope it will work

Comment: Thanks for answer and Yes Faizan I did same way but still savedInstance is coming as null. I had already added the comment for same

Comment: I have tried in `setRetainInstance(true);` on onCreat() and `if(savedInstanceState != null) {}` in onActivityCreated()

Comment: Try checking `if(savedInstanceState != null) {}` in onCreate as well.